# Xcode compiling app without images SFML

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sfml

I finished working on a Mac application. This application has been coded in Xcode. It used multiple images and fonts that formed the GUI. When I was adding these images, I had to put them in the directory of the debug file to be loaded (just placing them in the sidebar didn't work). Now, when I exported the application to my desktop, the app didn't load any images or fonts. I even tried adding the images to the same directory, but still none were loaded. Do you know what might be the issue? Perhaps, where should I place the files?

When the application is compiled within Xcode, everything works well, all the images are loaded. When I open the app in the debug directory, no images are loaded. And, if exported, still no images are loaded.

I don't know whether this is the issue with archiving, but I noticed that my SFML frameworks are displayed in red in Xcode. I don't know why as the framework directory is set correct, however the frameworks do load during build.

[image]

Comment: is the target membership has been set for these images in your Xcode?

Comment: Yes, both for app and appTests

Comment: then you should upload your code to github, its difficult to figure out what is going wrong without seeing it

Comment: Give us some SSCCE and we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to get the xcode 5 templates from the website and then put those into the developer folder in your lib.